# My Topology stopped after the first calling of emit()

Tags: java, twitter, analytics, twitter4j, apache-storm

We are working on Apache storm project and we need to do the following:

1 - count number of streamed tweetts from each city in SA. 
  2 - count the frequency of some specific words ( count of each of these specific words)

We used the tutorial of [StormTweetsSentimentD3Viz-master](https://github.com/P7h/StormTweetsSentimentD3Viz) and We could use it to accomplish (1).

However, when we tried to add the bolts to count the words as in [tweet_words_count](https://github.com/davidkiss/storm-twitter-word-count) the whole topology stopped after calling `collector.emit(new Values(lang, word));`

I tried to comment all the previous bolts and only run the splitterBolt but it alwayse stopping.

I also want to ask this: 
 - can I run the on same Spout, two different Bolts and I mean by that one to do the goal of (1) and other of (2) like the following:

```
    topologyBuilder.setSpout("twitterspout", new TwitterSpout());
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("statelocatorbolt", new StateLocatorBolt()).shuffleGrouping("twitterspout");
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("sentimentcalculatorbolt", new SentimentCalculatorBolt()).fieldsGrouping("statelocatorbolt", new Fields("state"));
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("jmsBolt", jmsBolt).fieldsGrouping("sentimentcalculatorbolt", new Fields("stateCode"));

    topologyBuilder.setBolt("WordSplitterBolt", new WordSplitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("twitterspout");
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("IgnoreWordsBolt", new IgnoreWordsBolt()).shuffleGrouping("WordSplitterBolt");
```

Please help in getting what is wrong.

Thank you

Comment: could you please post some logging details. Also you can chain as many bolt as you like in a single topology , each bolt is responsible for doing a specific task. So keeping a bolt to execute (1) and another to execute (2) make sense

Comment: Thank you for replaying @user2720864, Actually I'm running the topology from eclipse and I checked the log file of eclipse and it dosen't contain any information regarding the run.

Comment: did you uncheck the limit console configuration ? if the topology is terminated there supposed to be some exception thrown from storm .. what exactly do you see in the eclipse console

Comment: Thanks @user2720864 for coorperating, actullay the problem is solved. it run fine. However, I didn't know what the problem was but I tried to use a working bolt code that I had tested before and change it and it worked. I tried to understand what the different with the two code, but I didn't find what is worng. Any way thanks for trying to help me out.